# NSData writeToFile works on simulator but not on device

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, nsdata, writetofile

In my iphone app I am downloading some number of images from the web. It doesn't matter if it blocks the UI thread, in fact it needs to block UI thread till fully downloaded. Once done, I notify the UI to wake up and display them.

My (simplified) code goes like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    //call saveImageFromURL (params)
}
//Call to Notify UI to wake up and show the images

+(void) saveImageFromURL:(NSString *)fileURL :(NSString *)destPath :(NSString *)fileName
{
    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileURL]];

    NSFileManager * fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    BOOL bExists, isDir;
    bExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:destPath isDirectory:&isDir];

    if (!bExists)
    {
        NSError *error = nil;
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:destPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
            return;
        }
    }

    NSString *filePath = [destPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    [data writeToFile:filePath options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];
}
```

When I am done with my `for` loop, I am pretty sure that all images are stored locally. And it works fine in simulator.

However it does not work well on my device. UI wakes up before images are stored. And almost all images seem empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the destination path?

Comment: Check the error returned from writeToFile.

Comment: @Brad - its a dir under application support.

Comment: @Nicholas - Not that files do not download on device, but it seems to be waking the UI earlier than that.

Comment: 1) Remember that you can't write to the bundle file on the device, though the simulator will let you.  2) The handling of mixed case files is different on the two -- The simulator ignores case mismatch, but the device honors case.

Comment: @rmaddy - I check for it and create it with intermediate folders - even the app support one, yes.

Comment: @HotLicks - I know I am not modifying any bundle content here, just app support dir. And the cases are fine too.

Comment: did you confirm that the files are created at all on the device?

Comment: "It doesn't matter if it blocks the UI thread, in fact it needs to block UI thread till fully downloaded." <- That statement is terrifying, you should **never** block the UI thread, what you should do is download in the background and block the UI itself (if you truly need to) with a progress view or something similar.

Comment: @Pascal, thanks for drawing out the difference. So do you think my current method is not good?

Comment: @NiravBhatt No, I don't think your approach is good. Look at the `NSURLConnection` methods, they are asynchronous and are easy to implement (looks far more complicated than it is: [Apple Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)). This way you can fire off your requests and when each one of them comes in you can save the image, possible on a dedicated GCD queue.

Comment: My code uses lot of data fetching through AFNetworking. In their success blocks I am calling this file saving function. Do you think it is running on main thread? I am not sure how AFNetworking handles it's block operations - is it on UI thread or secondary thread. I put debugging code to get threadID inside and outside blocks, but it returns same thread - so I am really confused whether its asynchronous or synchronous?

Comment: I lately read some content on GCD, NSOperationQueue and realize that NSOperationQueue is what I should use. I know AFNetworking already uses that. I use it in other parts of my app. So should I use that here too? If anyone could answer me how I can asynchronoulsy load this URL image (to save as file, not display it) - I would accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I used `AFHttpClient enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations` to accomplish multiple file downloads.

Here is how it goes:

```
//Consider I get destFilesArray filled with Dicts already with URLs and local paths

NSMutableArray * opArray = [NSMutableArray array];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = nil;

for (id item in destFilesArray)
{
    NSDictionary * fileDetailDict = (NSDictionary *)item;
    NSString * url = [fileDetailDict objectForKey:@"fileURL"];
    if (!httpClient)
            httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    NSString * filePath = [photoDetailDict objectForKey:@"filePath"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];          

    operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:filePath append:NO];
    [opArray addObject:operation];
}    

[httpClient enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:opArray progressBlock:nil completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations)
{
    //gets called JUST ONCE when all operations complete with success or failure
    for (AFJSONRequestOperation *operation in operations)
    {

        if (operation.response.statusCode != 200)
        {                
            NSLog(@"operation: %@", operation.request.URL);
        }

    }

}];
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Check that if your device can download those images, visit the image URLs in Mobile Safari to test. `dataWithContentsOfURL:` will return nil OR it's not a correct image data, like 404 not found
2. Log errors of `[data writeToFile:filePath]` to see the details of saving .